# Hash table using only Java.Util.Arrays

Tags: java, hash, hashtable

I wanted to create a hash table for String values instead of int values, could someone tell me if this is possible to do?

The problem is that in the example we use the modulus of the newElementVal but I can't use this when the value is a String like "hello". I dont want to use an alternative method so if someone could point me in the right direction that would be great.

I have this example of the hash table:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

// If we think of a Hash Table as an array
// then a hash function is used to generate
// a unique key for every item in the array.
// The position the item goes in is known
// as the slot. Hashing doesn't work very well
// in situations in which duplicate data
// is stored. Also it isn't good for searching
// for anything except a specific key. 
// However a Hash Table is a data structure that 
// offers fast insertion and searching capabilities.

public class HashFunction {

    String[] theArray;
    int arraySize;
    int itemsInArray = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        HashFunction theFunc = new HashFunction(30);

        // Simplest Hash Function

        // String[] elementsToAdd = { "1", "5", "17", "21", "26" };

        // theFunc.hashFunction1(elementsToAdd, theFunc.theArray);

        // Mod Hash Function
        // This contains exactly 30 items to show how collisions
        // will work

        String[] elementsToAdd2 = { "100", "510", "170", "214", "268", "398",
                "235", "802", "900", "723", "699", "1", "16", "999", "890",
                "725", "998", "978", "988", "990", "989", "984", "320", "321",
                "400", "415", "450", "50", "660", "624" };

        theFunc.hashFunction2(elementsToAdd2, theFunc.theArray);

        // Locate the value 660 in the Hash Table

        theFunc.findKey("660");

        theFunc.displayTheStack();

    }

    // Simple Hash Function that puts values in the same
    // index that matches their value

    public void hashFunction1(String[] stringsForArray, String[] theArray) {

        for (int n = 0; n < stringsForArray.length; n++) {

            String newElementVal = stringsForArray[n];

            theArray[Integer.parseInt(newElementVal)] = newElementVal;

        }

    }

    // Now let's say we have to hold values between 0 & 999
    // but we never plan to have more than 15 values in all.
    // It wouldn't make sense to make a 1000 item array, so
    // what can we do?

    // One way to fit these numbers into a 30 item array is
    // to use the mod function. All you do is take the modulus
    // of the value versus the array size

    // The goal is to make the array big enough to avoid
    // collisions, but not so big that we waste memory

    public void hashFunction2(String[] stringsForArray, String[] theArray) {

        for (int n = 0; n < stringsForArray.length; n++) {

            String newElementVal = stringsForArray[n];

            // Create an index to store the value in by taking
            // the modulus

            int arrayIndex = Integer.parseInt(newElementVal) % 29;

            System.out.println("Modulus Index= " + arrayIndex + " for value "
                    + newElementVal);

            // Cycle through the array until we find an empty space

            while (theArray[arrayIndex] != "-1") {

                ++arrayIndex;

                System.out.println("Collision Try " + arrayIndex + " Instead");

                // If we get to the end of the array go back to index 0

                arrayIndex %= arraySize;

            }

            theArray[arrayIndex] = newElementVal;

        }

    }

    // Returns the value stored in the Hash Table

    public String findKey(String key) {

        // Find the keys original hash key
        int arrayIndexHash = Integer.parseInt(key) % 29;

        while (theArray[arrayIndexHash] != "-1") {

            if (theArray[arrayIndexHash] == key) {

                // Found the key so return it
                System.out.println(key + " was found in index "
                        + arrayIndexHash);

                return theArray[arrayIndexHash];

            }

            // Look in the next index

            ++arrayIndexHash;

            // If we get to the end of the array go back to index 0

            arrayIndexHash %= arraySize;

        }

        // Couldn't locate the key

        return null;

    }

    HashFunction(int size) {

        arraySize = size;

        theArray = new String[size];

        Arrays.fill(theArray, "-1");

    }

    public void displayTheStack() {

        int increment = 0;

        for (int m = 0; m < 3; m++) {

            increment += 10;

            for (int n = 0; n < 71; n++)
                System.out.print("-");

            System.out.println();

            for (int n = increment - 10; n < increment; n++) {

                System.out.format("| %3s " + " ", n);

            }

            System.out.println("|");

            for (int n = 0; n < 71; n++)
                System.out.print("-");

            System.out.println();

            for (int n = increment - 10; n < increment; n++) {

                if (theArray[n].equals("-1"))
                    System.out.print("|      ");

                else
                    System.out
                            .print(String.format("| %3s " + " ", theArray[n]));

            }

            System.out.println("|");

            for (int n = 0; n < 71; n++)
                System.out.print("-");

            System.out.println();

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: "a hash function is used to generate a unique key for every item in the array" - not usually... normally you need to deal with hash collisions. (It's unclear to me why you're reinventing the wheel here to start with... is it just to understand hash tables better?)

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to get a better understanding and wanted to use this example with words rather than numbers

Comment: Well it's currently very confusing, as you have strings which contain numbers and which are *assumed* to contain numbers. Either go "full text" or stick to just integers. Storing integers within strings makes the code more confusing and error-prone (e.g. comparing strings with `==`, which you're currently doing) without actually adding generality.